# Porting a Windows driver (.inf file) to an ARM64 machine (Windows 11 on Parallels VM, Apple Silicon M2)

Tags: windows, arm, driver

We have a Windows driver which has only one .inf file and a .cat file. From my understanding, it uses Windows usbrndis6.

It works well on Intel based Windows 11. Now we need to install it on ARM64 based Windows 11 (Parallels VM on Apple Silicon M2), but it didn't work. What could be wrong?

This is the mydriver.inf file:

```
[Version]
Signature           = "$Windows NT$"
Class               = Net
ClassGUID           = {aaaabbbb-1111-bbbb-aaaa-111122223333}
Provider            = %ProviderName%
DriverVer           = 07/23/2021,1.3.0.6
CatalogFile         = mydriver.cat
PnpLockDown         = 1

[Manufacturer]
%ProviderName%      = MyCoolDevice,NTx86.10.0,NTamd64.10.0,NTia64.10.0,NTarm64.10.0

;=============== Win 10 ==========================
[MyCoolDevice.NTx86.10.0]
%MyCoolDevice2410%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_096a
%MyCoolDevice2220%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08ac
%MyCoolDevice2230%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08b6
%MyCoolDevice2221%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08ad
%MyCoolDevice2320%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_0910
%MyCoolDevice2330%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_091a
%MyCoolDevice2340%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_0924

; Decoration for x64 architecture
[MyCoolDevice.NTamd64.10.0]
%MyCoolDevice2410%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_096a
%MyCoolDevice2220%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08ac
%MyCoolDevice2230%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08b6
%MyCoolDevice2221%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08ad
%MyCoolDevice2320%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_0910
%MyCoolDevice2330%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_091a
%MyCoolDevice2340%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_0924

; Decoration for ia64 architecture
[MyCoolDevice.NTia64.10.0]
%MyCoolDevice2410%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_096a
%MyCoolDevice2220%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08ac
%MyCoolDevice2230%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08b6
%MyCoolDevice2221%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08ad
%MyCoolDevice2320%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_0910
%MyCoolDevice2330%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_091a
%MyCoolDevice2340%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_0924

; Decoration for arm64 architecture
[MyCoolDevice.NTarm64.10.0]
%MyCoolDevice2410%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_096a
%MyCoolDevice2220%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08ac
%MyCoolDevice2230%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08b6
%MyCoolDevice2221%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_08ad
%MyCoolDevice2320%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_0910
%MyCoolDevice2330%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_091a
%MyCoolDevice2340%       = RNDIS.NT.10.0, USB\VID_2374&PID_0924

[RNDIS.NT.10.0]
Characteristics = 0x84   ; NCF_PHYSICAL + NCF_HAS_UI
BusType         = 15
; NEVER REMOVE THE FOLLOWING REFERENCE FOR NETRNDIS.INF
include         = netrndis.inf
needs           = usbrndis6.ndi
;AddReg          = Rndis_AddReg_Win7
*IfType            = 6    ; IF_TYPE_ETHERNET_CSMACD.
*MediaType         = 0    ; NdisMediumNative802_3
*PhysicalMediaType = 14   ; NdisPhysicalMedium802_3

; DDInstal.Services section
[RNDIS.NT.10.0.Services]
include     = netrndis.inf
needs       = usbrndis6.ndi.Services

;@@@ This is the common setting for setup
[ControlFlags]
ExcludeFromSelect=*

; No sys copyfiles - the sys files are already in-build
; (part of the operating system).
; We do not support XP SP1-, 2003 SP1-, ME, 9x.

[Strings]
ProviderName          = "MyCompany Limited"
MyCoolDevice          = "My Cool Device"
MyCoolDevice2410      = "My Cool Device 2410"
MyCoolDevice2220      = "My Cool Device 2220"
MyCoolDevice2230      = "My Cool Device 2230"
MyCoolDevice2221      = "My Cool Device 2221"
MyCoolDevice2320      = "My Cool Device 2320"
MyCoolDevice2330      = "My Cool Device 2330"
MyCoolDevice2340      = "My Cool Device 2340"
```

Thanks very much!